# Pass %d to strcat() fucntion

Tags: c, c-strings, strcat

I'm trying to pass something like this to a string but it does not work. I don't understand very well this function so I was hoping someone would explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
strcat(string,("%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", x->n1, x->n2, x->n3, x->n4, x->n5, x->s1, x->s2, x->s3, x->s4, x->s5, x->s6));
```

Comment: You need [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).  Just like `printf`, but it "prints" to a string instead of your screen.  For extra credit, use [`snprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), which lets you ensure you don't overflow your destination buffer.

Comment: Did you try to read something about this function before trying? Voodoo programming never works https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you are trying to do is the following

```
sprintf( string + strlen( string ), 
         "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", 
         x->n1, x->n2, x->n3, x->n4, x->n5, 
         x->s1, x->s2, x->s3, x->s4, x->s5 );
```

Also instead of `sprintf` you can use `snprintf` that is safer.

The character array `string` must contain a (possibly empty) string and be large enough to accommodate appended strings.